# whatever i use as inputs, outputs are all zeros

Tags: c++, vector

This is a question i am working on:

- Prompt the user to enter five numbers, being five people's weights. Store the numbers in a vector of doubles. Output the vector's numbers on one line, each number followed by one space.
- Also output the total weight, by summing the vector's elements.
- Also output the average of the vector's elements.
- Also output the max vector element.
  So far this is the code i have

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  using namespace std;

  int main() {
     const int NEW_WEIGHT = 5;
     vector<float> inputWeights(NEW_WEIGHT);
     int i = 0;
     float sumWeight = 0.0;
     float AverageWeight = 1.0;
     int maxWeight = 0;
     int temp = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < NEW_WEIGHT; i++){
        cout << "Enter weight "<< i+1<< ": ";
        cout << inputWeights[i]<< endl; 
        cin>> temp;
        inputWeights.push_back (temp);

     }


     cout << "\nYou entered: ";

     for (i =0; i < NEW_WEIGHT- 1; i++) {

        cout << inputWeights.at(i)<< " ";
     }
     cout<< inputWeights.at(inputWeights.size() - 1) << endl;

     for (i =0; i < NEW_WEIGHT; i++){

         sumWeight += inputWeights.at(i); 

     }
     cout <<"Total weight: "<< sumWeight<< endl;

     AverageWeight = sumWeight / inputWeights.size();

     cout <<"Average weight: "<< AverageWeight<< endl;

     maxWeight= inputWeights.at(0);
     for (i =0; i < NEW_WEIGHT- 1; i++){
         if (inputWeights.at(i) > maxWeight){
            maxWeight = inputWeights.at(i);
         }
      }

      cout<< "Max weight: "<< maxWeight << endl;

      return 0;
  }
  ```

When i run this code, whatever inputs i use(for the cin>>(...)), i get all zero's as output and i do not know why.  can i get some help please.

**update**
cleaned up the code a little by getting rid of the **cout<< inputWeights[i]<< endl;**
and by adjusting **vector inputWeights;** at the beginning of the program.But the outputs are still not exactly what they are supposed to be. Instead, only the first 2 inputted values make it as outputs. Any reason why? thanks

**update this is the right or correct code. Hope it helps someone in future.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int NEW_WEIGHT = 5;
   vector <float> inputWeights;
   int i = 0;
   float sumWeight = 0.0;
   float AverageWeight = 1.0;
   float maxWeight = 0.0;
   float temp = 0.0;

   for (i = 0; i < NEW_WEIGHT; i++){
      cout << "Enter weight "<< i+1<< ": "<< endl;
      cin>> temp;
      inputWeights.push_back (temp);

      }


      cout << "\nYou entered: ";

   for (i =0; i < NEW_WEIGHT- 1; i++){

      cout << inputWeights.at(i)<< " ";
   }
      cout<< inputWeights.at(inputWeights.size() - 1) << endl;

    for (i =0; i < NEW_WEIGHT; i++){

       sumWeight += inputWeights.at(i); 

      }
   cout <<"Total weight: "<< sumWeight<< endl;

       AverageWeight = sumWeight / inputWeights.size();

   cout <<"Average weight: "<< AverageWeight<< endl;

      maxWeight= inputWeights.at(0);
    for (i =0; i < NEW_WEIGHT- 1; i++){
       if (inputWeights.at(i) > maxWeight){
          maxWeight = inputWeights.at(i);
          }
    }

   cout<< "Max weight: "<< maxWeight << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint: look at how push_back() works

Comment: @LWimsey it appends whatever is in temp to the vector inputWeights.

Comment: exactly, so your vector grows from 5 to 10, because you initialized it with 5 zero's and those are still there

Comment: from all the feedbacks, i guess the problem is at the "prompting user input" level. right? @Jack Deeth do you mean i should get rid of **vector<float> inputWeights(NEW_WEIGHT);**line? if i do, how do i declare the vector i am going to use then. thanks

Comment: He meant you need to get rid of '(NEW_WEIGHT)' so that the vector declaration becomes: vector<float> inputWeights; This is an empty vector that you will populate with push_back()

Comment: maxWeight should still be the same type as all of your data (other weights). Also you are declaring your weights as `float` and your vector as a vector of floats, but your temp variable is a double and you are pushing that into the vector. This can lead to truncation. Also when it comes to `std::vector` you do not need to use the `.at()` method. You can use the overloaded subscript `[]` operator. It is much faster at indexing. The only difference is there is no bounds checking so you will have to be aware of the size of that vector's internal array.

Comment: oh your are right. i should have used floats instead of double.

Answer (score 2):

You're making a `vector` of size 5:

```
const int NEW_WEIGHT = 5;
vector<float> inputWeights(NEW_WEIGHT);

// == 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Then, in your input loop, you're adding new values to the end:

```
inputWeights.push_back (42);

// == 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42
```

Then you're outputting the first five elements which were always zero.

You need to choose one thing or the other: either set the size of the vector at the start of the program, or grow the vector with `push_back` for as long as there's input. Both are valid options.

You can clean up your code and fix the problems by adopting modern C++ (as in, C++11 and later) idiom. You don't need to fill your code with `for(int i = 0; i < something; i++)` any more. There's a simpler way.

---

```
// Size fixed in advance:
vector<float> weights(NUM_WEIGHTS);

for (auto& weight : weights) { // note it's `auto&`
  cout << "\nEnter next weight: ";
  cin >> weight; // if it was plain `auto` you'd overwrite a copy of an element of `weight`
}
```

---

```
// Size decided by input:
vector<float> weights; // starts empty this time

cout << "Enter weights. Enter negative value to stop." << endl;
float in;
while (cin >> in) {
  if(in < 0) {
    break;
  }
  weights.push_back(in);
}
```

---

In either case, you can then play with the filled vector using another range-based `for`:

```
cout << "You entered: ";
for (const auto& weight : weights) {
  cout << weight << " ";
}
```

You'll also need to remove the `cout << inputWeights[i] << endl;` line from your input loop if you resize the vector during input - as written you'd be reading elements which don't exist yet, and will probably get an array-index-out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: @SergeyA you're right, need to strike the `cout << inputWeights[i]` line at the start of the input loop.

Comment: from all the feedbacks, i guess the problem is at the "prompting user input" level. right?

Answer (score 1):

When you create define your inputWeights you are putting 5 items into it with default values.

```
vector<float> inputWeights(NEW_WEIGHT);
```

Change it to be just

```
vector<float> inputWeights;
```

And get rid of this line in your code or comment it out

```
cout << inputWeights[i]<< endl;
```

Comment: ohh ok!! thanks i have a better output now. but it is still not exactly what it is supose to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for from the requirements of your program.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> weights;

    double currentWeight = 0.0;
    const unsigned numberOfWeights = 5;
    std::cout << "Enter " << numberOfWeights << " weights" << std::endl;
    unsigned i = 0;
    for ( ; i < numberOfWeights; ++i ) {
        std::cin >> currentWeight;
        weights.push_back( currentWeight );
    }

    std::cout << "These are the weights that you entered: " << std::endl;
    for ( i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i ) {
        std::cout << weights[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    double totalWeight = 0.0;
    std::cout << "The total of all weights is: ";
    for ( i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i ) {
        totalWeight += weights[i];
    }
    std::cout << totalWeight << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The average of all the weights is: " << (totalWeight / numberOfWeights) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The max weight is: ";
    double max = weights[0];
    for ( i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i ) {
        if ( weights[i] > max ) {
            max = weights[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The culprit to your problem for seeing all 0s as output is coming from these two lines of code:

```
const int NEW_WEIGHT = 5;
vector<float> inputWeights(NEW_WEIGHT);
```

which is the same as doing this:

```
vector<float> inputWeights{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

you are then looping through up to 5 elements using `NEW_WEIGHT` when it would be easier to use `inputWeights.size()` when traversing through containers.

**Edit - Condensed Version**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> weights;

    double currentWeight           = 0.0;
    const unsigned numberOfWeights = 5;
    unsigned i = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter " << numberOfWeights << " weights" << std::endl;
    for ( ; i < numberOfWeights; ++i ) {
        std::cin >> currentWeight;
        weights.push_back( currentWeight );
    }

    double totalWeight = 0.0;
    double max         = weights[0];
    std::cout << "These are the weights that you entered: " << std::endl;
    for ( i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i ) {
        std::cout << weights[i] << " ";   // Print Each Weight
        totalWeight += weights[i];        // Sum The Weights

        // Look For Max Weight
        if ( weights[i] > max ) {
            max = weights[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The total of all weights is: " << totalWeight << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The average of all the weights is: " << (totalWeight / numberOfWeights) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The max weight is: " << max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone. i did not see that my Temp  variable was of type int instead of double. changingthat gave me what iwanted as output. @Francis Cuglar i appreciate it.

Comment: @TINA15 I did make a modification to the program by adding in a `const unsigned` for the amount of weights to be added. This way all you have to do is change that number and the full algorithm or program works regardless of how many inputs there are to be expected. All the loops and calculations will be based off that unsigned `numberOfWeights`.

Comment: What I've shown above can be condensed to doing less for loops, but I chose to do it this way to show each step clearly. I could of easily done it in 2 separate for loops with the first loop populating the vector and the second for loop printing all elements of the vector and calculating both the sum of all values and finding the max value. The average doesn't require any loops.